# How to make two WPF DatePicker-s displayed with different width regardless initial Selected date values?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datepicker

Tow `DatePicker` controls initially displayed with different `Width` when one has `SelectedDate` as `null` and another initialized with not null `DateTime`.

The problem statement here is - after user entered date value into the control that has `null` initial value the `Width` remains the same.

How would it be possible to configure `DatePicker` initial display so that it will be the same size regardless whether initial `SelectedDate` is null or not

There is following layout definition in XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

And view-model has following property definition:

```
private DateTime? _selectedDate1;
private DateTime? _selectedDate2 = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime? SelectedDate1
{
    get { return _selectedDate1; }
    set
    {
        _selectedDate1 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate1));
    }
}
public DateTime? SelectedDate2
{
    get { return _selectedDate2; }
    set
    {
        _selectedDate2 = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedDate2));
    }
}
```

Comment: Does or should the `DatePicker` ever expand beyond its initial size? If not, you can just assign a fixed `Width`. Is there any `DatePicker` that always has a date value and therefore the desired size?

Comment: @thatguy based on the theme (font) the ```DatePicker``` could change, so specifying constant values for ```Width``` won't work in generic case

Answer (score 1):

Set the `SharedSizeGroup` property of both `ColumnDefinitions` to the same value and the `Grid.IsSharedSizeScope` attached property of the parent `Grid` to `true`:

```
<Grid Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="a" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="5">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="a" Width="Auto"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: @Tim: Did you try this?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Grid>
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="35"/>
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
<Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
</Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

<DatePicker Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"
    SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate1, Mode=TwoWay}"/>

<DatePicker Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"
    SelectedDate="{Binding Path=SelectedDate2, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

Comment: thank your answer. The proposed solution is not generic enough. Say we need to take in account different themes (font-size), are there any way to improve so that parent layout won't be fixed size?

Comment: instead of writing <RowDefinition Height="35"/> u do like <RowDefinition Height="0.5*"/> .